# Adobe Illustrator - Scripting crashes when trying to fit to artboards command

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

```
activeDocument.fitArtboardToSelectedArt()
```

When calling this command, AI crashes on AI 5.1/6 32bit and 64bit versions. I can use the command from the menu. Has anyone encountered this? does anyone know of a work around?

The full code.

```
    function exportFileToJPEG (dest) {
    if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {

        activeDocument.selectObjectsOnActiveArtboard()
        activeDocument.fitArtboardToSelectedArt()//crashes here
        activeDocument.rearrangeArtboards()

        var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsJPEG();
        var type = ExportType.JPEG;
        var fileSpec = new File(dest);
        exportOptions.antiAliasing = true;
        exportOptions.qualitySetting = 70;
        app.activeDocument.exportFile( fileSpec, type, exportOptions );
    }
}
var file_name = 'some eps file.eps'
var eps_file = File(file_name)


var fileRef = eps_file;



if (fileRef != null) {
    var optRef = new OpenOptions();
    optRef.updateLegacyText = true;
    var docRef = open(fileRef, DocumentColorSpace.RGB, optRef);
}

exportFileToJPEG ("output_file.jpg")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce the bug with AI CS5.

It seems that `fitArtboardToSelectedArt()` takes the index of an artboard as an optional parameter. When the parameter is set, Illustrator doesn't crash. (probably a bug in the code handling the situation of no parameter passed)

As a workaround you could use:

```
activeDocument.fitArtboardToSelectedArt(
               activeDocument.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()
                                       );
```

to pass the index of the active artboard with to the function. Hope this works for you too.

Also it's good practice to never omit the semicolon at the end of a statement.

Comment: This is still a "problem" in Illustrator CC 2017 (ver. 22.0.1). The documentation (the object model viewer) still states that the artboard index is an optional parameter, but Illustrator crashes inevitably when omitting it. Thanks for this solution, @Jonas!